# SQL injection with username and password

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection, code-injection

```
 $sel1 = mysql_query ("SELECT ID, name, locale, lastlogin, gender,
 FROM  USERS_TABLE
 WHERE (name = ’$user’ OR email = ’$user’) AND pass = ’$pass’");
```

I tried logging in with the user as (with the user I want being 'test'):

```
     test')");--
```

I figured that should eliminate the check for pass but I did not any ideas what I did wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: He is not asking how to prevent it.

Comment: I see 3 syntax errors here. I also don't understand your question's title.

Comment: Alright, my bad. Did understand the question the other way. (Obviously I wasn't the only one confused).

Comment: well I am out of this question. @ me if you need me. *ciao*

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use '`"`'. The `"` in that string is is not part of the string itself. Try this:

```
test')--
```

Answer (score -1):

In your case just use `mysql_real_escape_string` for checking ([documentation](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string)).

```
$user = mysql_real_escape_string($user);
$pass = mysql_real_escape_string($pass);
$sel1 = mysql_query (...
```

See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1) however.

Note that `mysql_query()` is nowadays deprecated.

Comment: I'm given that vulnerable sql statement and the goal is to input the injection into the username field the the UI so that I can login with any username. I guess i should have phrased my question better.

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string` is deprecated.

Comment: Sure it is, identically to `mysql_query` which was present in the question (and mentioned in the answer).